# is there a way to ask sql server job to wait for an exe to finish before going on to next step

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql server 2005 job with three steps.

1. exec stored Procedure A
2. run exe
3. exec stored Procedure B

I want to wait for the exe to finish before executing step 3. Is there an easy way to do this?

Worst comes to worse I can write an EXE that does something like this:

```
   myLinqDataContext.executeProcedureA
   Dim p as process = Process.run(path to exe from step 2)
   p.waitforexit
   myLinqDataContext.executeProcedureB
```

But I am wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Job Step will wait until the EXE completes and returns.

Note, however, that some EXEs are asynchronous (or more likely, start another EXE/copy asynchronously), so that they return to their callers even though they have not completed yet.  You need to either disable this behavior or find/write something else that will monitor it and only return when it exits.